# call_user_function_array() and __construct

Tags: php, frameworks, constructor

I'm working on a simple framework, and I'm having a slight problem. I'd like to use call_user_function_array() to pass parameters to a function. That's fine, except the function I want to pass it to is __construct. I can't create an instance of an object with cufa(), and by instantiating an object, and then using cufa to call that instance's __construct(), I run into problems with a broken class because I'm calling the constructor twice (and one time it's called wrong.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the reflection API is the best shot here.

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('className');
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($argsArray);
```

Comment: +1 for relection, call_user_func_array seems to have bug when calling referenced arguments.